# Abnormal behavior on Debian 9 after crashes

Tags: debian, login

After I tried to install swift on my Debian 9 machine, Suddenly I faced a big problem (I couldn't access Debian GUI) I solved this issue by some terminal command like

`sudo apt-get install gdm3` and `apt-get install firmware-misc` and more.

Now I can access my GUI normally but,

1. I cannot open my user account (on login screen I can insert my user name and password but I cannot login, The two text boxes become empty after I hit login) when I logged in with root I can get access to my user name via terminal.
2. I cannot open Firefox browser.
3. I cannot open Opera browser.

The message file on `/var/log/message`

says `Error reading existing Xauthority: Failed to open file “/home/amraly/.Xauthority”: Permission denied`

I think that number 2 and 3 can solve by install them again but number one is my main problem.

Comment: What did you do just before "suddenly"? What were the terminal commands you issued afterwards? What happens when you try to launch the browsers? Are there any relevant information in any of the system's logfiles?

Comment: Consider adding clarifications in the question rather than as comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian has a synaptic package manager from system tools. I fixed all the broken packages I found it in the synaptic manager, then my account returned and my Debian copy returned normal without any error.

Answer (score 0):

## For your browsers

You can run a browser as root by `un-sandboxing` it.

I made a simple script that can help enable or disable different browsers in root. The script will present you a menu which will enable or disable a browser based on your selection.

[**Github repo link**](https://github.com/david-kariuki/linux-unsandbox-browsers-cli)

## For your desktop environment.

I also made a script that can install many desktop environments, debug and help you switch the defaults. If your desktop environment has any issues, it will automatically fix them.

[Github link](https://github.com/david-kariuki/linux-desktop-environment-tool-cli)

Use the profile link incase the repo links wount work.

[Profile link](https://github.com/david-kariuki/)